# Finding the average distance between coordinates

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, average, distance

I have two public datasets of 1) bike trips and 2) stations where I need to find the station with the highest average trip distance. I have joined the tables from the two datasets

- `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire`
- `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations`

Each trip has a start station and an end station. Trips will usually have a different end station than start stations so the distance is different each time. Want to find out which start station has the longest trips/distance on average to its end station, meaning which trips are on average to the furthest end stations for bikers.

I would want the 1) output to be something like this:

```
Trip  Start_station_coordinate  start_st_name  end_station_coordinate  end_st_name   km_dist
 1    POINT(-0.123 51.123)      A-station      POINT(-0.123 51.123)     B-station      ??
 2    POINT(-0.123 51.123)      C-station      POINT(-0.123 51.123)     D-station      ??
 3    POINT(-0.123 51.123)      D-station      POINT(-0.123 51.123)     F-station      ??
```

...and 2) group by the start_station which has the highest average km_distance for each trip. So something like this:

```
start_station   average_distance_descending

  A-station     20 km      
  B-station     15 km 
  C-station     3  km
```

My code is a JOIN I cant incorporate the above into my query (as I am totally new to sql). I've tried the following with the problematic line at the very end:

```
 `SELECT ST_GeogPoint(stations1.longitude, stations1.latitude) as WKT1
   ,stations1.id
   ,ST_GeogPoint(stations2.longitude, stations2.latitude) as WKT2
   ,stations2.id as id_2  
   ,trips.end_station_id
   ,trips.start_station_id
   from bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire as trips
   Inner JOIN bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations as stations1
   ON trips.start_station_id = stations1.id 
   Inner JOIN bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations as stations2
   ON trips.end_station_id = stations2.id
   order by AVG(st_distance(WKT1, WKT2))`
```

BigQuery says "*The ORDER BY clause only allows aggregation if GROUP BY or SELECT list aggregation is present at [22:5]"*, with reference to the last line. I have been wrecking my brains on how to find highest average distances (if possible at all) and how to combine it into my JOIN operation.

How do I write this in the right way in order to find right distances?? 
This is an extremely important task for and I am on a deadline with no hope and hoping for help as soon as possible

Comment: it is extremely important that you formulate what exactly logic you have in mind along with **simplified** example and example of **expected output**. just showing questionable query usually never works!

Comment: thanks good to know - I've reformulated a bit- please check if its makes more sense now or dont hesitate to let me know if not (its my first post)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH output_1 AS (
  SELECT 
    ST_GEOGPOINT(stations1.longitude, stations1.latitude) AS WKT1,
    stations1.name AS start_st_name,
    ST_GEOGPOINT(stations2.longitude, stations2.latitude) AS WKT2,
    stations2.name AS end_st_name,
    ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOGPOINT(stations1.longitude, stations1.latitude), ST_GEOGPOINT(stations2.longitude, stations2.latitude)) AS dist
  FROM bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire AS trips
  INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations AS stations1
    ON trips.start_station_id = stations1.id 
  INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations AS stations2
    ON trips.end_station_id = stations2.id
), output_2 AS (
  SELECT 
    start_st_name AS start_station, 
    ROUND(AVG(dist), 2) AS average_distance
  FROM output_1
  GROUP BY start_st_name
)
SELECT *
FROM output_2
ORDER BY average_distance DESC
LIMIT 10
```

with output

```
Row start_station                               average_distance     
1   Blackfriars Station, St. Paul's             5895.44  
2   Bonner Gate, Victoria Park                  4105.8   
3   Walworth Square, Walworth                   3751.54  
4   Bourne Street, Belgravia                    3681.56  
5   Clarence Walk, Stockwell                    3351.18  
6   Clapham Road, Lingham Street, Stockwell     3293.93  
7   Clapham Common North Side, Clapham Common   3268.38  
8   Limburg Road, Clapham Junction              3156.89  
9   Wandsworth Rd, Isley Court, Wandsworth Road 3148.16  
10  Sugden Road, Clapham    3107.68
```

Comment: it was a while ago, but wish to thank you so much for the help! it was extremely useful and hope you carry on in the future

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the "average distance" between stations. 2 stations will always have the same distance between them.

Let's create first a table with a `JOIN` of all possible station combinations:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_eu.stations AS (
   SELECT station1, station2
     , ST_DISTANCE(
         ST_GeogPoint(station1.longitude, station1.latitude)
         , ST_GeogPoint(station2.longitude, station2.latitude)) distance
   FROM `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations` station1
   JOIN `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_stations` station2
   USING(id)
); 
# 1.4 sec elapsed, 76.1 KB processed
```

And now you can augment the original table with this data - and sort by distance, if that's what you want:

```sql
SELECT
 distance, station1, station2
 ,hire.duration
 ,hire.bike_id
 ,hire.end_date
 ,hire.end_station_id
 ,hire.end_station_name
 ,hire.start_date
 ,hire.start_station_id
 ,hire.start_station_name
 from `bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire` as hire
JOIN temp_eu.stations
ON hire.start_station_id = station1.id 
AND hire.end_station_id = station2.id
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much but I've been a bit unclear and edited my questions. I'm trying to figure out highest average distance from a start stations to an end station, where the end station is almost always different from the start station. A rider can basically rent a bike from the start station (which is public), cycle it to a different end station depending on each riders/bikers end station destination. Would it be possible to re-check again as it would help in a major way?